# Confusion with CampaignMember Object

Tags: query, leads, lead-conversion, campaign, campaign-member

I'm confused with `LeadId` and `ContactId` fields, these are contacts or leads associated with a campaign, to my understanding, it's who was a prospect (lead or contact) at the moment of associating with campaign. When I run a query:

`select count(id) from CampaignMember where LeadId != null and ContactId != null`

And... I get a list of CampaignMembers with both lead and contact id fields! How?

In addition, when I join converted leads on CampaignMembers (`contactId` and `convertedContactId`) I see that some of the associated contacts were leads before, while `leadId` is empty. Doesn't make sense. Thanks!

Comment: So you are trying to reconcile what you observe - a CampaignMember with both a ContactId and LeadId against the documentation: `Each record has a unique ID, and must contain either a ContactId or a LeadId, but can't contain both` ?

Comment: @crop1645 exactly, though I couldn't find any such statement in documentation (either `LeadId` or `ContactId` but never both together).

Comment: The doc is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm?search_text=campaignmember. I just did a query in my PROD org and saw I had 29 with both contactId and leadId for the current MONTH

Comment: If a contact has been converted from a lead it may still have its old  leadId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience working with the CampaignMember object, I see the following scenarios:

**1. `CampaignMember` with `Lead`**
`CampaignMember.LeadId` is populated
`CampaignMember.ContactId` is null

**2. `CampaignMember` with `Contact`**
`CampaignMember.LeadId` is null
`CampaignMember.ContactId` is populated

**3. `CampaignMember` with `Contact` who is already a converted `Lead`**
`CampaignMember.LeadId` is null
`CampaignMember.ContactId` is populated

**4. `CampaignMember` with `Lead`, then `Lead` is converted to `Contact`**
`CampaignMember.LeadId` is populated
`CampaignMember.ContactId` is also populated

In writing custom logic to determine if I should be using the `Contact` or `Lead` lookup on `CampaignMember`, I first check if `ContactId` is populated. If it's not, then I fallback to the `Lead`.

Comment: excellent - I'd suggest you provide feedback to the SFDC doc as said doc is at best misleading or worse, in error

Answer (score 1):

The API doc on [CampaignMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_campaignmember.htm?search_text=campaignmember) states:

> Each record has a unique ID, and must contain either a ContactId or a
>   LeadId, but can't contain both.

I observed the following in my PROD org using this query:

```
select campaign.name, name, leadId, lead.firstname, lead.lastname, lead.isConverted, 
      contactId, contact.firstname, contact.lastname 
  from CampaignMember 
  where LeadId != null and ContactId != null and createdDate = THIS_MONTH
```

I had 29 hits. Everyone of them had `Lead.isConverted = true`

The doc gets even weirder:

> Supported Calls For API version 15.0 and earlier:create(), delete(),
>   describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(),
>   query(), retrieve(), update(), upsert()
>
> For API version 16.0 and later: upsert()

but this can't be right - I just did the query above in V35.0

There is also this statement under Usage

> Standard fields from a Contact or Lead are associated with the
>   CampaignMember object but you can’t query them directly. To include a
>   lead’s Phone in your query, for example, query the field from the Lead
>   object.

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Phone FROM Lead) FROM CampaignMember
```

This syntax doesn't work at all. Standard dot notation syntax worked just fine.

I'm not a regular user of these objects so someone else may have a better answer but I can see why you are confused.

Comment: The doc you linked in the comment on the question states this: `Only use a ContactId or LeadId, but not both, *unless* you want to track lead-based campaign members you convert to contacts.` so according to it you can have both (except when inserting - `Any attempt to *create* a single record with both results in a successful insert but only the ContactId will be inserted` the campaign member) kind vague and requires a lot of reading between the lines

Comment: yeah, I saw that too and decided that I couldn't trust anything written in the doc, @Ualj has a good experiential evidence answer below